# Laravel 8 Route not defined even route is defined

Tags: php, web, laravel-8, laravel-routing

This error is comeup while i working on laravel 8

```
Route [product.details] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\resources\views\livewire\shop-component.blade.php)
```

here is the route i made Route Page web.php

```
Route::get('/product/{slug}',DetailsComponent::class)->name('product.details');
```

this is line of view where i want that route View Page shop-component.balde.php

```
<a href="{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug]) }}" title="{{$product->name}}">
```

and this one is the Details Component code

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;

class DetailsComponent extends Component
{
    public $slug;
    Public function mount($slug){
 
        $this->slug = $slug; 
    }

    public function render()
    {
     $product = Product::where('slug', $this->slug)->first();
    return view('livewire.details-component',['product'=>$product])->layout('layouts.base'); 
    }
}
```

I think this php code doesnot get route of product.details at the same time i create middleware file  and define a different route in it this route is working in this page but not Product.details.
Kindly help me i am stuck from 1 week here

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
php artisan route:list
```

to show a list of registered routes - make sure it shows up there. If it doesn't, use

```
php artisan route:clear
```

to clear Laravel's route cache

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because of your route. It's not write in the correct way. You have first to make your DetailsComponent::class is bracket then you have to give the name of the method you want to use in this class.

`Route::get('/product/{slug}', [DetailsComponent::class, 'method name'])->name('product.details');`

Comment: we can use route without method calling and i put answer above this thing is working great

Comment: Yea of course. But for this one, it's a resource `controller` according to the syntax. You have to use the resource method instead of `get`

Comment: Actually you may be right but for the solution of this question is what i said i dont know why but livewire or my pc cause cache error too much so when ever i clear my cache its appeared to be ok

Comment: Yea you are right bro